# How to get the all the raw touch points at a particular instant for a tap?

Tags: android, touch, android-source

When the touchscreen is tapped once, the finger touches multiple x,y positions on the screen by virtue of the finger being fat. But android only gives me one x,y position at a time (For example, if I use adb shell getevent, it gives me only one x-y coordinate at a time. Of course for a tap it gives multiple x,y positions since the tap lasts for some time and it gives the x-y position for each fraction of that time if x-y slightly changes.) At each instant there are more than 50-100 pixels that I am touching - presumably android uses some algorithm to reduce all the touch signals into one x-y position. Is there a way I can get those multiple raw touch signals at every pixel I am touching at the same time? I have a rooted device and am willing to delve into android source code if required.

Answer (score 3):

Android reports the total touch area as an ellipse through several MotionEvent APIs.

The major axis of the touch ellipse: [MotionEvent.getTouchMajor()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html#getTouchMajor%28int%29)

The minor axis of the touch ellipse: [MotionEvent.getTouchMinor()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html#getTouchMinor%28int%29)

The orientation of the touch ellipse: [MotionEvent.getOrientation()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html#getOrientation%28int%29)

Comment: Can you confirm that you have these methods working?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22050028/android-finger-detection-orientation-and-ellipse and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22032486/ontouch-moitonevent-gettouchminor-and-gettouchmajor-alwasys-the-exact-same-numbe

Report problems with these methods

Comment: It's been about two years since I've used these, but they have definitely worked for me in the past on a number of devices. Have you also tried using `getHistoricalOrientation`, `getHistoricalTouchMajor`, etc? It might also be worth trying `getSize` and `getHistoricalSize`.

Comment: Interesting, we got a coding error on historical methods. But I would like some more details: Are you saying you had success with historical methods or those mentioned in your answer?
And could you perhaps elaborate on which devices you have achieved the wanted result on? (Elaborating on the wanted result would also be very much appreciated) :)

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't recall the devices. Where I worked at the time had several hundred different Android devices. I tried it on my Moto X, and got major/minor numbers that reflected the touch size. But major/minor were always equal. And orientation was always 0. So that seems like a common scenario. I would imagine something that ships with a stylus (like Galaxy Note), would return better values. You shouldn't be getting coding errors on the historical methods. Did you check MotionEvent.getHistorySize() first? Looking at both the current and historical events is usually a good idea.