# How to get all touched pixels on android

Tags: android, touch

Is there a way to get every single touched pixel during a touch event? I understand that Android can provide an eclipse but I would like to access every single pixel that was touched for research purposes.

I understand this is the same question as [How to get the all the raw touch points at a particular instant for a tap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18345300/how-to-get-the-all-the-raw-touch-points-at-a-particular-instant-for-a-tap)

Did something change since then to provide this data now on Android devices or possibly iOS?

Comment: are you need a pixel on screen means its color code or position.

Comment: for every touch event I would like to get an array of all pixels with value 0 - not touched or 1 - touched. Or something like that.